# SELECT inside a CASE clause with an IN

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I would like to do this:

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN var in (SELECT var FROM var_table) THEN 'var1'
      ELSE 'var2' 
      END AS myvar
```

But it complains about this. How can I avoid having to paste the whole list of var in var_table inside the query. This is Teradata by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a quite old version of Teradata as Scalar Subqueries like this are supported since TD13.

Even if they are supported i would always try to rewrite them (in any DBMS not only TD). Yours is a hidden Outer Join (assuming it's the first few lines from a query including a FROM):

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN t1.var IS NOT NULL THEN 'var1' ELSE 'var2' END AS myvar
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN var_table AS t2
ON t1.var = t2.var
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN var is null THEN 'var2'
      ELSE 'var1' 
      END 
from var_table
```

Comment: This is simply not returning the same result.

Comment: say I get var="hello". And there is no "hello" in var_table. I want that case to be "var2". I don't see in your code how that's going to be the case?